# How to use Visual State Manager with Button.ImageSource property

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set up a toggle button like this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button#creating-a-toggle-button

However, my button has a font icon inside of it. The button with the font itself works fine. The problem is when I try setting the ImageSource property from the Visual State Manager.

Code is below:

```
<FontImageSource x:Key="fileImageSource" Glyph="&#xF0E6;"
  Color="Gray"
  FontFamily="{ DynamicResource MaterialIconsFontFamily }"
  Size="28" />

<Button Margin="20,10,20,0" 
    Text="Email Disabled (click to enable)" 
    FontFamily="{ DynamicResource MaterialIconsFontFamily }"
    Style="{StaticResource PaynuverDisabledButtonStyle}"
    ImageSource="{StaticResource fileImageSource}">
</Button>

<local:ToggleButton Toggled="OnBoldButtonToggled"
   Margin="20,10,20,0"
   FontFamily="{ DynamicResource MaterialIconsFontFamily }">
   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="ToggleStates">
        <VisualState Name="ToggledOff">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Email Disabled (click to enable)" />
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource DisabledButtonStyle}" />
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="{StaticResource fileImageSource}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState Name="ToggledOn">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Email Enabled" />
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</local:ToggleButton>
```

With the following code i get an error: "The PropertyName of ToggleButton.ImageSourceProperty is not ImageSource"

Comment: Got it working with Code Behind. Still interested to see why it wouldn't work in xaml

Comment: Is the error a compile error? I used your code on my side and I didn't see the error. And I use the latest version of Xamarin.forms.

Comment: Nope it was a run-time error. I'll see if i can try it in a sample project.

Comment: OK, once you can upload a sample here, we will check it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are trying to create a custom control "ToggleButton".

> The PropertyName of ToggleButton.ImageSourceProperty is not ImageSource

This message warns you about a missing bindable property, or a simple mistake in the property call.

By the way, did you try to use [Switch control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/switch) ?